# Код Python по последовательному открытию файлов Excel в Python и работа с ними

Tags: python, excel

не получается написать цикл по поиску строк по значению столбца в нескольких файлах Excel. Пробовал объединять в один большой файл, но такой способ мне не подходит, т.к. необходимо ещё фильтровать строки. Как вариант, чтобы открывался каждый файл отдельно и там искало, потом переходило к следующему файлу. Как сделать код на цикличное открытие файлов
В каждом файле есть строки с названиями и знанием в столбце цифровыми. Мне надо отобрать строки со знанием столбца 91, но если с аналогичным названием в строке есть знание столбца больше, чем 91, то такую строку мне не надо брать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну, оберните это всё в цикл по файлам. Только инициализацию коллекции данных сделайте до этого цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос недостаточно полный - не хватает информации о том, какую библиотеку для работы с `xlsx` вы используете.
Конкретно реализовать цикличную работу файлов не трудно - ниже для примера код из одного моего проекта, который решает эту задачу. Думаю, будет нетрудно переписать его под ваш случай

```py
import openpyxl


def get_xlsx(path):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=path)
    work_sheet = wb['Sheet']

    return work_sheet


def value_search(_): pass


files = ['a.xlsx', 'b.xlsx', 'c..xlsx']

for file in files:
    table = get_xlsx(file)
    value_search(table)
```

Не уверен, что это буквально то, что нужно вам, но, надеюсь, поможет в поиске решения

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема вот в чем: мне надо отфильтровать строки по значению столбца. Если объединить в один файл, появляются взаимоисключающие значения. Потому мне надо искать по отдельности в каждом файле ексель

Comment: И у меня почему-то не работает wb=. Программа думает, что я пытаюсь задать значение переменной

Comment: @АртёмМетеж как выбрать и фильтровать строки - смотрите документацию к библиотеке. "не работает wb=" - в каком плане не работает, что в traceback?

Comment: Invalid syntax показывает. Если делаю wb = openpyxl.load_workbook, пишет underfined name 'openpyxl'

Comment: @АртёмМетеж а вы установили и импортировали openpyxl?

Comment: Да, конечно....

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Оказывается все работало, проблема была в другом